# NFT marketplace with NFT collections as individual smart contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, nft

I have developed a NFT marketplace with solidity. When a collection of NFTs is created solidity deploys a new contract for each collection, however I am not sure this is the common way of doing it, since it seems wasteful and more difficult to maintain (if we consider implementing upgradable contracts).

Generally, how do marketplaces handle the creation of new collections? Are all collections stored in one single smart contract? or each collection becomes a deployed smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, I code a smart contract to have functionalities to list NFTs and connect the contract to a frontend user interface where users can mint NFT dynamically by specifying the name and descriptions. After the NFT has been successfully minted, it's display graphically on the frontend. Each creation is a considered a transaction on the blockchain, and I can console log the values (e.g. current account address, number of NFTs created, an array containing the NFTs, and their maximum supply) after each transaction in the browser, so I know the transaction went through and a new NFT has been minted successfully.

Comment: So your marketplace seems to have one single collection where all the NFTs belong to, however my question is about multiple collections, like in opensea where each collection of NFTs such as Bored Ape, CryptoPunks, etc, contains thousands of NFTs.